# Does $ f\in Sp\{f_{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\} $?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

Define $ f_{0}(x)=1,x\in [0,1) $ and $ f_{n}(x)=x^{n},x\in [0,1) $ for each $ n\in \mathbb{N} $. Also define $ f(x)=\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty f_{n}(x) $ for all $ x\in [0,1) $.

My question : Dose $ f $ belong to the linear span of $ \{f_{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\} $ ? (i.e. Does $ f\in Sp\{f_{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\} $ ?)

Could you give me a help ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest answer for your question is "No".

Justification: Observe that the series $ \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty f_{n}(x) $ converges to $ \dfrac{1}{1-x} $ for each $ x\in [0,1) $. Therefore for each $ x\in [0,1) $, $ f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1-x} $. Then $ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1^{-}}f(x)=\infty $.

Assume that $ f\in \text{ linear span }\{f_{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\} $. Then there exist $ n_{1},n_{2},...,n_{k}\in \mathbb{N} $ and $ r_{1},r_{2},...,r_{k}\in \mathbb{R} $ such that $ f(x)=r_{1}f_{1}(x)+r_{2}f_{2}(x)+...+r_{k}f_{k}(x) $ for all $ x\in [0,1) $. Then we have that $ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1^{-}}f(x)=r_{1}+r_{2}+...+r_{k}\neq \infty $. This is a contradiction.

Hence $ f\notin \text{ linear span }\{f_{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\} $.